# Can someone explain the solution to the final temple puzzle?

Tags: the-witness

The greatest thing about the puzzles in The Witness is that they make perfect sense... or so I thought, until I came across one I just couldn't solve.
I ended up looking up the solution (much to my own annoyance) and to my surprise, I still didn't understand how you were supposed to know how to solve it.

Can anyone explain the logic behind it?

The solution I found:

> [image]

Comment: Check the solution in this [video tutorial](https://youtu.be/7U4fmKvuG1s?list=PL5dr1EHvfwpNYbS_yqCZg30lEnpiEF6O2&t=621).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hint 1:

> You're not seeing the whole picture...

Hint 2:

> The buildings on the island were built a while ago.  The temple area is in especially bad shape.

Solution:

> This puzzle is very old, and the tree branch has broken.  You can find the missing piece on the floor near your feet.

Comment: Perfect answer! I wish I'd read your hints first!

Comment: Nice use of hints! :) - I solved this by doing what you're supposed to do, but I literally thought I was being 'crazy' by thinking what I was thinking. And then, of course, it 'pinged' to say it was correct. I just sat there with my mouth wide open for 30 seconds.